# "OK, Google" Command To Launch Music App

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, music, google-voice-actions

I am trying to find the voice command to launch the app on my `Note Edge` to launch the app called `Music`  It is a stock Android App, but anytime I say Music or anything of that nature, it immediately loads Play Music.

Is there a voice command to launch the `Music` app, or is there a way to customize voice controls on what voice command opens which app?

Answer (score 0):

I have a **Sony Phone** with both **Stock Music player** and **Google Play Music player**.

> This works for me, I'm not sure for Samsung Phones. But you can give it a try.

- I manage to open my **Stock** Music player from Google Assistant by saying "`open music from Sony`".
- To open the play music, i say "`open music from Google`" (or) "`open play music`" (The app name).